# Encoding a binary as BASE64 in Java and decoding it in node.js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encoding, pentaho

I have a Pentaho process that is is base64 encoding a binary (pdf) via java - with this command:

> Step: Load File Content In Memory
>     Outputs: pdf_content

Then

> Step: Javascript 
>     Outputs: encString

```
var encString = new Packages.java.lang.String( Packages.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64( pdf_content.getBytes() ) );
```

Then

> Step: Rest Client (posts data)

On the NodeJs side

```
const binary = new Buffer(base64Encoded, 'base64');
```

The problem is that the binary file on the node side differs from that on the source (i have access to and can copy the files around).

Further confusing the matter I introduced an intermediate step saving the base64Encoded string out to disk prior to decoding it.  I also then opened the original file (from the Pentaho Side) and encoded that using the

```
 Buffer(fs.readFileSync(originalPath)).toString('base64')
```

and compared the base 64 encoded versions of each.  I was hoping to confirm that the algorithm is different (although there is no guarantee). The files themselves were the same length, and started and finished with no differences.  Scattered about the file were bunch of minor differences.  1 byte here 1 byte there.

Other bits: Apache.Commons...Base64 uses "rfc 2045" Buffer on the Node Js side uses "rfc 4648" (I may be misreading the description).  Questions,

1. Is there a known way to communicate base64 between a Java encoding and Node Js decoding?
2. Are there other recommendation on base64 encoding in Pentaho?

Comment: FWIW, [RFC 4648](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648) seems to be the actual base64 encoding and mentions meeting some restrictions from [RFC 2045](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt), so they don't seem incompatible at first glance.

Comment: Yes, I figured as much.  I was hoping to be able figure out how to translate between the two, but that doesn't seem likely.  I can't seem to find a compatible implementation on the node side...  I think my Java implementation is gong to be limited to the pre installed 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you encode it on the Java side:

in Java 7 using Google guava's `com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding` and `com.google.common.io.Files`:

```
byte[] data = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(bytes).getBytes();
Files.write(data, new File(outputFile));
```

in Java 8 using `java.util.Base64` and `java.nio.file.Files`/`java.nio.file.Paths`:

```
byte[] data = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);
Files.write(Paths.get(outputFile), data);
```

and decode on the node side (synchronous version):

```
var fs = require("fs");
var buf fs.readFileSync("fromJava.dat");
var res = new Buffer(buf.toString(), "base64").toString("utf-8");
```

And here are the corresponding Java-side tests (for Java8 native `java.util.Base64` and for Guava's `com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding`) invoking node.js process and proving correctness:

```
@Test
public void testJ8() throws IOException {
  String input = "This is some UTF8 test data, which also includes some characters "
    + "outside the 0..255 range: ❊ ✓ ❦. Let's see how we get them to node and back";

  byte[] data = Base64.getEncoder().encode(input.getBytes());
  Files.write(Paths.get("fromJava.dat"), data);

  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"node",  "-e",
    "console.log(new Buffer(require('fs').readFileSync('fromJava.dat').toString(), 'base64').toString('utf-8'))"});
  assertEquals(input, new Scanner(p.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\n").next());
}
```

Test run:

> Process finished with exit code 0

```
@Test
public void testJ7() throws IOException {
  String input = "This is some UTF8 test data, which also includes some characters "
    + "outside the 0..255 range: ❊ ✓ ❦. Let's see how we get them to node and back";

  byte[] data = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(input.getBytes()).getBytes();
  Files.write(data, new File("fromJava.dat"));

  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"node",  "-e",
    "console.log(new Buffer(require('fs').readFileSync('fromJava.dat').toString(), 'base64').toString('utf-8'))"});
  assertEquals(input, new Scanner(p.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\n").next());
}
```

Test run:

> Process finished with exit code 0

Both tests executed with Java 8 on OSX/unix but Guava 19 used here is fully compatible with Java 7 and if the `node` executable is on the path in Windows then there is no reason why the tests would not run there (provided it can also evaluate a script after the `-e` argument, no idea).